# Adding SPM support to Objective-C Pod: provide include directory

Tags: swift, objective-c, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I am currently trying to add SPM support to a Pod with Objective-C code (https://github.com/keighl/KTCenterFlowLayout) by myself and I was wondering how to expose the header files so it can be implemented in a swift project.

I got inspired by this PR, which basically does the same thing:
https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell/pull/356/commits

My question is: how did `woxtu` create those alias-C-Header files `MGSwipeButton.h` and `MGSwipeTableCell.h` in the `include` directory in order to make it work? (Everything happens in this commit: https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell/pull/356/commits/9ee590f54269c09f203ae5c99f13d08e5ec78672)

Comment: Are you talking about `publicHeadersPath` in `target` parameter?

Comment: @Cy-4AH: I am talking about these two files in particular:

https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell/blob/9ee590f54269c09f203ae5c99f13d08e5ec78672/MGSwipeTableCell/include/MGSwipeTableCell/MGSwipeButton.h

https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell/blob/9ee590f54269c09f203ae5c99f13d08e5ec78672/MGSwipeTableCell/include/MGSwipeTableCell/MGSwipeTableCell.h

Comment: Ah! It's Symbolic Links. `ln -s source target`

Comment: @Cy-4AH thanks! I will try it

Comment: @Cy-4AH works like a charm, thank you, please answer this thread, I will mark it as resolved